# Can I create "inc" folder inside wordpress root directory?

Tags: wordpress

Can I create inc folder "mysite.com/inc/" inside wordpress root directory as per wordpress standard. I need to place my supported php files.

Please help.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

**Technically you can** and it's even going to stay there when you upgrade.

However: if you put stuff into Wordpress you may seriously want to consider using Wordpress' plugin and theme architecture. If you are writing an include for a theme, put it within the theme's directory. If it's a plugin, place it as a plugin. This will allow for easy packaging in case you need to move to different Wordpress instance.

For a more detailed walkthrough of the directory structure [check out this post](http://www.howtospoter.com/web-20/wordpress/wordpress-guide-dissection-of-file-structure).

Comment: Thanks for your information. I became to notice the "inc" folder inside root directory of existing wordpress website. I need to upgrade the version. So I had little confusion on wordpress code standard structure. So we need to keep the "inc" folder after upgrade with essential changes. Thanks dude.